# Cells in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

I'm working with [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) and using [this (QuickStart.pdf)](http://www.miglayout.com/mavensite/docs/QuickStart.pdf) and [this(Cheat sheet)](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/docs/cheatsheet.html).

Why the cells doesn't work? I'm suppose this should make 3 rows and 2 colums. JLabel and JTextField on each row. 
What should I change to make it work as I've expected?

My code:

```
private Container serverInfo() {
JPanel oServeruJP = new JPanel();

this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
JLabel serverLB = new JLabel("Server: ");
JTextField serverTF = new JTextField("none");
JLabel portLB = new JLabel("Port: ");
JTextField portTF = new JTextField("none");
JLabel stavServeruLB = new JLabel("Stav serveru: ");
JTextField stavServeruTF = new JTextField("Odpojen");

oServeruJP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Informace o serveru:"));

oServeruJP.add(serverLB, "cell 0 0");
oServeruJP.add(serverTF, "cell 1 0");
oServeruJP.add(portLB, "cell 0 1");
oServeruJP.add(portTF, "cell 1 1");
oServeruJP.add(stavServeruLB, "cell 0 2");
oServeruJP.add(stavServeruTF, "cell 1 2");
return oServeruJP;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the layout for your outer container (`this`) to `MigLayout`, rather than the panel you're adding your components to (`oServeruJP`).

Try instead:

```
oServeruJP.setLayout(new MigLayout());
```

Comment: Thanks I found this mistake about 20 minutes ago :( Now I'm finding way how to delete this question. Bad typo :/

Comment: I've run into that in the past too, just leave it in case someone runs into the same problem.